# What is the difference between LIKE '[A-D]%' ; and BETWEEN 'A' AND 'D' ; in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, rdbms

What is the difference between

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE name LIKE ' [A-D] %' ;
```

and

```
BETWEEN 'A' AND 'D'
```

in *SQL server*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me assume you are talking about *SQL Server*, not *MySQL*.

SQL Server has limited extensions of `LIKE` that support character ranges.  So, you are comparing:

```
where name like '[A-D]%' 
where name between 'A' and 'D'
```

The difference is simple.  A name longer than "D" that starts with "D" matches the first condition but not the second.  For instance, 'Dionysis' and 'Dracula' match the `like` but not the `between`.

The equivalent comparison would be:

```
where name >= 'A' and name < 'E'
```

Comment: Thank you now i understand the difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

`LIKE '[A-D]%'` checks if the first character of a string is an A,B,C or D.
`BETWEEN 'A' AND 'D'` checks if a string falls between 'A' and 'D' when sorting. For a string of a single character, they will act the same (depending on collation).

`LIKE '[A-D]'`, without the wildcard, is equivalient `BETWEEN 'A' AND 'D'` when comparing a single character.

`LEFT(textcolumn, 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'D'` is equivalient to `textcolumn LIKE '[A-D]%'` - that is, only looking at the first character of the string.

Comment: without the wildcard , what does this means.

Comment: @SanjitPrasad . . . That part of the answer is wrong.

Comment: Without the wildcard means that I removed the `%` from the `LIKE` expression. And no, it's not wrong, @GordonLinoff. Those two tests will return true, false and null in the same situations, afaik. When will they behave differently?

Comment: @gnud . . . `like` without the wildcard would match four  character, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'.  Well, it might also match lower case and accented versions, but the length of any matching string would be one character.

Comment: You're completely right, I meant they're equivalient when comparing a single character. I realize now my answer is a bit unclear about that.